# ValueError: could not convert string to float during NMEA analysis

Tags: floating-point, gps, tuples, python-3.4, nmea

I'm learning how to analyze the data I'm getting from my gps and have been studying a book about crafting visual transformation scripts. I'm using python34 and the data I'm looking at looks like this:

```
['$GPRMC', '2454', 'A', '3553.5295', 'N', '13938.657', 'E', '0', '43.1', '180700', '7.1', 'W', 'A*3F', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$GPRMB', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'A', 'A*0B', '', '', '', '', '']
['$GPGGA', '2454', '3553.5295', 'N', '13938.657', 'E', '1', '5', '2.2', '18.3', 'M', '39', 'M', '', '*7F', '', '', '', '', '']
['$GPGSA', 'A', '3', '1', '4', '7', '16', '20', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3.6', '2.2', '2.7*35', '', '']
['$GPGSV', '3', '1', '9', '1', '38', '103', '37', '2', '23', '215', '0', '4', '38', '297', '37', '5', '0', '328', '00*70']
['$GPGSV', '3', '2', '9', '7', '77', '299', '47', '11', '7', '87', '0', '16', '74', '41', '47', '20', '38', '44', '43*73']
['$GPGSV', '3', '3', '9', '24', '12', '282', '00*4D', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$GPGLL', '3553.5295', 'N', '13938.657', 'E', '2454', 'A', 'A*4F', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$GPBOD', '', 'T', '', 'M', '', '*47', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$PGRME', '8.6', 'M', '9.6', 'M', '12.9', 'M*15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$PGRMZ', '51', 'f*30', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$HCHDG', '101.1', '', '', '7.1', 'W*3C', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$GPRTE', '1', '1', 'c', '*37', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['$GPRMC', '2456', 'A', '3553.5295', 'N', '13938.657', 'E', '0', '43.1', '180700', '7.1', 'W', 'A*3D', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Right now I'm concentrating on  $GPGSV and $GPRMC lines.

I have a definition that is to process the GPS data, NMEA 0183 format:

```
def process_gps_data(data):
    """Processes GPS data, NMEA 0183 format.

Returns a tuple of arrays: latitude, longitude, velocity [km/h],
time [sec] and number of satellites.
See also: http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm.
    """

    latitude  = []
    longitude = []
    velocity  = []
    t_seconds = []
    num_sats  = []

    for row in data:
        if row[0] == '$GPGSV':
            num_sats.append(float(row[3]))
        elif row[0] == '$GPRMC':
            t_seconds.append(float(row[1][0:2])*3600 + \
            float(row[1][2:4])*60+float(row[1][4:6]))
        latitude.append(float(row[3][0:2]) + \
            float(row[3][2:])/60.0)
        longitude.append((float(row[5][0:3]) + \
            float(row[5][3:])/60.0))
        velocity.append(float(row[7])*NMI/1000.0)

    return (array(latitude), array(longitude), array(velocity), array(t_seconds), array(num_sats))


(latitude, longitude, velocity, t_seconds, num_sats) = process_gps_data(y)
```

But it seems that I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\nmea_practice.py", line 112, in <module>
    (latitude, longitude, velocity, t_seconds, num_sats) = process_gps_data(y)
  File "C:\Python34\nmea_practice.py", line 102, in process_gps_data
    float(row[1][2:4])*60+float(row[1][4:6]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I thought python3.x should work fine with its default floating-point divisions?

Could you tell me what I should be doing differently?

---

ADDED INFO.

I originally manually delimited the csv by commas because the rest of my script required the data to be split to create this definition:

```
#Counts the number of times a GPS command is observed
def list_gps_commands(data):
    """Counts the number of times a GPS command is observed.

Returns a dictionary object."""

    gps_cmds = dict()
    for row in data:

        try:
            gps_cmds[row[0]] += 1 
        except KeyError:
            gps_cmds[row[0]] = 1

    return gps_cmds

print(list_gps_commands(x))
print ("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")
```

The original data looked like this before I delimited it by commas manually:

```
['$GPRMC,002454,A,3553.5295,N,13938.6570,E,0.0,43.1,180700,7.1,W,A*3F']
```

Any suggestions on how I could 'split' that to suffice enough for the 'list_gps_commands and solve the floating error?

---

ADDED INFO 2

What I'm getting is raw nmea data from my gps device. Right now it happens to be Garmin_etrex_summit. I have the data inside a csv and the data is one long string for each row. If you can go ahead and look at the formatting of a $GPRMC line, you'll see that in total there are 13 fields separated by commas.

```
$GPRMC,002454,A,3553.5295,N,13938.6570,E,0.0,43.1,180700,7.1,W,A*3F
```

Each field stands for something and is supposed to be in a designated format.

[image: RMC Data Format]

```
row[1] = hhmmss.sss (UTC Time) 
row[3] = ddmm.mmmm (Latitude)
row[5] = ddmm.mmmm (Longitude)
row[7] = anything with decimal place (Velocity in knots)
```

Comment: *"Each field stands for something and is supposed to be in a designated format."* - but `2454` does not confirm to `hhmmss.sss`. I think, you should check your input data. Also, this question grows up for a third time - you should create a new post, if your original problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data, `row[1]` is `'2454'`, however, you are trying to get a slice from 4 to 6:

```
float(row[1][4:6])
```

Which returns an empty string. `float` does not know, how to handle it:

```
In [6]: float('')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ddb0cdb80cb6> in <module>()
----> 1 float('')

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

In case if you have truncated data, you may manually extend it with leading zeroes:

```
In [11]: '2454'.zfill(6) # When `'2454'` is a `str`
Out[11]: '002454'

In [12]: '{:06}'.format(2454) # Another way
Out[12]: '002454'

In [13]: float('{:06}'.format(2454)[4:6])
Out[13]: 54.0
```

---

**UPD**:

Seems like your data could be parsed as a regular [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
In [17]: list(csv.reader(['$GPRMC,002454,A,3553.5295,N,13938.6570,E,0.0,43.1,180700,7.1,W,A*3F']))
Out[17]: 
[['$GPRMC',
  '002454',
  'A',
  '3553.5295',
  'N',
  '13938.6570',
  'E',
  '0.0',
  '43.1',
  '180700',
  '7.1',
  'W',
  'A*3F']]
```

As you can see, `002454` parsed without any problems, and you don't have to expand it with leading zeroes.

Comment: I think the issue is that this is coming from a csv file and I manually delimited the workbook by comma's. I am now testing the 'raw' version of the gps data and seeing if I can do a function like 'row = row.split(","). The 'raw' data for the gprmc looks like this:$GPRMC,002454,A,3553.5295,N,13938.6570,E,0.0,43.1,180700,7.1,W,A*3F ............this would make a difference I believe considering that row[1] would become '002454' IF I figure out how to split the data

Comment: I updated my original question...could you take a look?

Comment: @Daniel, I've updated my answer as well, please, take a look on it

Comment: Ok...I'm trying to figure out how I can adapt that parsing to my code

Comment: in your In [13]: float('{:06}'.format(2454)[4:6]) -- how would you format that if the format of row[1] is supposed to be hhmmss.sss ?

Comment: @Daniel, please, clarify. What is the actual value of `row[1]` when it supposed to be `hhmmss.sss`? I'm not sure, if `str.format` is applicable here, you should probably use [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime)

Comment: I updated my question at the bottom to give a bit more detail.